# unity "съедает" качество картинки

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-ui, unity3d-faq

Начал изучение Unity, решил сделать платформер, а спрайт(на глаз - векторный) в .png формате, на scene нормально отображается, а в game - все спрайты пикселизируются(чтобы было видно - нажмите на картинку!) скрины прикладываю:
[image: экран сцены]
[image: экран игры]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил вопрос поправив в окне game в выпадающем сверху окна списке "Free aspect" или что у кого будет там стоять... в общем - снимаем галочку с "Low resolution aspect ratios"